# Group every n elements

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want an array of arrays taking the elements up to a certain amount like:

```
b = group(a,4) = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6],[5,6],[6]]
```

I tried:

```
a.each_cons(4) {|x1,x2,x3,x4| b[a.index(x1) = [x1,x2,x3,x4]}
```

but the resulting array doesn't have the last three elements:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],[2, 3, 4, 5],[3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
a.map.with_index { |e, i| a.slice(i, 4) }
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 4]
#⇒ [2, 3, 4, 5]
#⇒ [3, 4, 5, 6]
#⇒ [4, 5, 6]
#⇒ [5, 6]
#⇒ [6]
```

Comment: thank a lot @mudasobwa. I question that about 2 level method `array.map.with_index`. How it's processed ?

Comment: `a.each_index.map` is more straightforward.

Comment: or `{|_, i| a[i..i+4]}`, without `slice`

Comment: @ilya how about last three elements ?

Comment: @ilya In what sense is `a[i..i+4]` better than `slice(i, 4)`? To me, the latter is much better.

Comment: @sawa, both `a[i, 4]` and `slice[i, 4]`  are same, I've just suggested an alternative in comments, more readable for me, maybe it will be more readable for somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

asize = a.size
  #=> 6 
a.each_index.map { |i| a[i, [4, asize-i].min] }
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6], [6]]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
asize = a.size
  #=> 6 
enum0 = a.each_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:each_index> 
enum1 = enum0.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:each_index>:map>
```

Have a close look at the return value for `enum.map`. You will see that it can be thought of as a compound enumerator.

We can see the elements that will be generated by `enum1` by converting it to an array.

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

We can now pass each element generated by `enum1` to the block for the mapping.

```
i = enum1.next
  #=> 0
a[i, [4, asize-i].min]
  #=> a[0, [4, 6].min]
  #=> a[0, 4]
  #=> [1,2,3,4]
```

so the first element of `a`, `1`, is mapped to `[1,2,3,4]`.

The remaining steps are as follows.

```
i = enum1.next         #=> 1 
a[i, [4, asize-i].min] #=> [2, 3, 4, 5] 

i = enum1.next         #=> 2 
a[i, [4, asize-i].min] #=> [3, 4, 5, 6] 

i = enum1.next         #=> 3 
a[i, [4, asize-i].min] #=> [4, 5, 6] 

i = enum1.next         #=> 4 
a[i, [4, asize-i].min] #=> [5, 6] 

i = enum1.next         #=> 5 
a[i, [4, asize-i].min] #=> [6] 

i = enum1.next         #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.